# How to scale chart values to start from 100 and end to 100

Tags: seasonality, finance

First time writing this so forgive my ignorance.

Anyway, I'm trying to scale the S&P500 daily closing values to make them start from 100 and end near 100, hope it makes sense.

So let's say we have a week worth of data like this:

1.1.2020 --> 3100
1.2.2020 --> 3110
1.3.2020 --> 3120
1.4.2020 --> 3110
1.5.2020 --> 3115

How do I bring the daily closing prices to start from 100 and end around 100 in order to have a chart that starts from one point and ends at a similar level to where it started, by the way I need to do this on a Google sheet.

Hope it kinda makes sense.

Comment: What is your purpose for re-scaling the data? Would subtracting [first value] from every datapoint then adding 100 to every datapoint be enough?

Comment: By far the simplest solution is to set all the closing prices to 100.  This perhaps surprising--but obviously correct--answer indicates you need to explain what you're hoping to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Just divide each value on your vector by the first value and then multiply by $100$ :

$$
y = (3100, 3110, 3120, 3110, 3115)
$$

I guess what you're looking for is :

$$
(y/3100) * 100  = (100.00, 100.32, 100.64, 100.32, 100.48)
$$

**Edit** : Just realize you also want the series to end at 100 ? If so, it looks like a [Brownian bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge) is what you might be looking for.